# Find Connecting Flights in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a search to find connecting flights between two airports using Django. I have two flights CCU to DEL and DEL to DXB. But when I search CCU to DXB, it returns an empty QuerySet. .It is not showing any result.

```
# views.py

origin = Airport.objects.get(iata_code='CCU')
destination = Airport.objects.get(iata_code='DXB')
origin_flights = Flight.objects.filter(origin_airport=origin)
destination_flights = Flight.objects.filter(destination_airport=destination)

connecting_flights = Flight.objects.filter(
        Q(origin_airport__in=origin_flights.values('destination_airport')) & 
        Q(destination_airport__in=destination_flights.values('origin_airport'))
)

print(connecting_flights)
```

The models

```
# models.py

class Airport(BaseModel):
    airport_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    airport_country = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    iata_code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    
class Flight(BaseModel):
    flight_number = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    origin_airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="flight_origin")
    destination_airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="flight_destination")
    departure_date = models.DateField()
```

I also tried this.

```
origin_iata_code = 'CCU'
destination_iata_code = 'DXB'

connecting_flights = Flight.objects.filter(
        Q(origin_airport__iata_code=origin_iata_code) &
        Q(destination_airport__iata_code__in=Flight.objects.filter(
            origin_airport__iata_code__in=Flight.objects.filter(
                origin_airport__iata_code=origin_iata_code
            ).values('destination_airport__iata_code')
        ).values('destination_airport__iata_code')) &
        Q(destination_airport__iata_code=destination_iata_code)
)

print(connecting_flights)
```

Comment: Did you try this : `connecting_flights = Flight.objects.filter(Q(origin_airport__in=origin_flights) & Q(destination_airport__in=destination_flights))` ?

Comment: ValueError: Cannot use QuerySet for "Flight": Use a QuerySet for "Airport".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try it, in my environment it works.

```
    origin = Airport.objects.get(iata_code='CCU')
    destination = Airport.objects.get(iata_code='DXB')
    origin_flights = Flight.objects.filter(origin_airport=origin)
    destination_flights = Flight.objects.filter(destination_airport=destination)

    connecting_flights1 = Flight.objects.filter(
        origin_airport__in=origin_flights.values('origin_airport'))

    connecting_flights2 = Flight.objects.filter(
            destination_airport__in=destination_flights.values('destination_airport'))

    connecting_flights = connecting_flights1.union(connecting_flights2)
    print("CF ", connecting_flights)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is simply :

```
connecting_flights = Flight.objects.filter(
    origin_airport__iata_code='CCU',
    destination_airport__iata_code='DXB'
)
```